# Override system "URL not found" template in Intershop 7.10?

Tags: intershop, isml

We are trying to override the default template for the "URL not found" page. The template name is URLError.isml and it is located in the sld_system_app cartridge. When we try to override the template via "Override existing" wizard, the template doesn't get found, even though the sld_system_app is in the cartridge dependency hierarchy:

[image]

At the same time, any pipeline from the same cartridge (sld_system_app) can normally be overriden. For example we can override the URLMapping.pipeline which is using the URLError.isml:

[image]

It is the same for any ISML template located in the sld_system_app cartridge. None of the templates can be overriden.

Is there some way of overriding the default ISML or do we really need to override the pipeline to do so?

UPDATE #1:

We have managed to get the wizard working, after some studio restarts and cleaning the target and refreshing gradle dependencies. However, after creating the template through the wizard, deploying the file on the server and restarting the server, the override is still not working. We are still getting the system page.

This is the overriden template in our custom cartridge:

[image]

And this is the content of the cartridgelist.properties:

```
cartridges=\
    libs \
    runtime \
    3rd_oracle \
    pf_cartridge \
    pf_objectgraph \
    pf_objectgraph_guice \
    servletengine \
    component \
    file \
    emf \
    pf_extension \
    pf_property \
    jmx \
    app \
    messaging \
    pf_kafka \
    cache \
    pipeline \
    isml \
    orm \
    configuration \
    businessobject \
    core \
    orm_oracle \
    orm_mssql \
    wsrp \
    rest \
    bc_authorization \
    bc_repository \
    bc_spreadsheet \
    bc_foundation \
    bc_i18n \
    bc_application \
    bc_auditing \
    bc_region \
    bc_service \
    bc_mail \
    bc_ruleengine \
    report \
    bc_auditing_orm \
    bc_organization \
    bc_approval \
    bc_validation \
    bc_address \
    bc_address_orm \
    bc_user \
    bc_user_orm \
    bc_captcha \
    bc_pdf \
    bc_processchain \
    bc_processchain_orm \
    ui_web_library \
    ac_captcha_recaptcha \
    ac_mail \
    ac_ruleengine_drools \
    ac_pdf_flyingsaucer \
    pf_axis2 \
    ac_eureka \
    bc_transport \
    bc_transport_orm \
    bc_transport_azure \
    dev_swagger \
    pf_jrockit \
    dev_lilith \
    etest \
    tool_webtest \
    dev_query \
    pf_objectgraph_test \
    pf_businessobject_test \
    pf_core_test \
    pf_rest_test \
    pf_orm_test \
    orm_oracle_test \
    orm_mssql_test \
    pf_property_test \
    pf_messaging_test \
    bc_foundation_test \
    bc_service_test \
    bc_auditing_test \
    bc_application_test \
    bc_i18n_test \
    bc_validation_test \
    bc_user_test \
    bc_address_test \
    bc_approval_test \
    ac_ruleengine_drools_test \
    bc_processchain_test \
    ui_web_library_test \
    pf_axis2_test \
    bc_handler_chain \
    bc_urlrewrite \
    bc_image \
    xcs \
    bc_shipping_data \
    bts \
    btc \
    monitor \
    smc \
    bc_pricing \
    bc_pmc \
    bc_pmc_auditing \
    bc_pmc_validation \
    bc_preview \
    bc_preview_orm \
    pmc_rest \
    bc_search \
    bc_mvc \
    bc_productbinding \
    bc_customer_segment \
    bc_customer \
    bc_customer_orm \
    bc_catalog \
    bc_catalog_orm \
    bc_product \
    bc_product_orm \
    bc_product_validation \
    bc_rating \
    bc_rating_orm \
    bc_product_rating \
    bc_product_rating_orm \
    bc_customer_catalog_filter \
    bc_customer_catalog_filter_orm \
    bc_wishlist \
    bc_wishlist_orm \
    bc_addresscheck \
    bc_basket \
    bc_basket_orm \
    bc_basket_service \
    bc_order \
    bc_order_orm \
    bc_order_service \
    bc_warranty \
    bc_profanitycheck \
    bc_requisition \
    bc_tendering \
    bc_giftpackaging \
    bc_shipping \
    bc_promotion \
    bc_recommendation \
    bc_marketing \
    bc_marketing_impex \
    bc_abtest \
    bc_abtest_orm \
    bc_payment \
    bc_payment_orm \
    bc_giftcard \
    bc_taxation \
    bc_product_pricing \
    bc_product_pricing_orm \
    bc_orderprocess \
    bc_order_impex \
    bc_payment_service \
    bc_gdpr \
    bc_store \
    bc_store_orm \
    bc_dashboard \
    bc_dashboard_orm \
    sld_system_app \
    as_system \
    sld_pmc \
    sld_pdf \
    sld_preview \
    sld_mcm \
    sld_ch_b2c_base \
    sld_ch_sf_base \
    ac_bmecat \
    sld_enterprise_app \
    sld_ch_base \
    sld_ch_partner_plugin \
    sld_ch_consumer_plugin \
    ac_giftcard_std \
    ac_payment_std \
    ac_taxation_std \
    ac_customer_segment_std \
    sld_ch_b2c_image \
    app_sf_rest \
    app_sf_rest_b2c \
    app_sf_rest_smb \
    app_sf_rest_recomm \
    ac_oci \
    ac_cxml \
    ac_order_export_xml \
    ac_order_submission_service \
    ac_order_history_service \
    ac_order_status_import_xml \
    migration \
    sld_ch_consumer_orderimport_es64 \
    app_bo_rest_job \
    app_bo_catalog \
    app_bo_dashboard \
    app_bo_gdpr \
    as_backoffice \
    ac_search_solr \
    ac_search_solr_bo \
    ac_addresscheck_demo \
    ac_payment_demo \
    ac_customer_segment_demo \
    ac_webhook_inventory \
    as_contactcenter \
    app_sf_contactcenter_rest \
    app_bo_contactcenter_cobrowsing \
    ac_gtm \
    ac_gtm_google_analytics \
    ac_gtm_sf \
    app_bo_transport \
    dev_handler_chain \
    dev_organizationinfo \
    dev_bostyleguide \
    dev_basketinfo \
    dev_apiinfo \
    dev_payment \
    bc_pmc_test \
    bc_handler_chain_test \
    bc_xcs_test \
    bc_shipping_test \
    bc_mvc_test \
    bc_product_test \
    bc_product_orm_test \
    bc_bts_test \
    bc_pricing_test \
    bc_requisition_test \
    bc_marketing_test \
    bc_marketing_impex_test \
    bc_preview_test \
    sld_preview_test \
    ac_customer_segment_std_test \
    bc_customer_test \
    bc_customer_catalog_filter_orm_test \
    bc_wishlist_test \
    ac_giftcard_std_test \
    bc_warranty_test \
    bc_promotion_test \
    bc_basket_test \
    sld_ch_b2c_base_test \
    sld_enterprise_app_test \
    sld_ch_consumer_plugin_test \
    bc_catalog_test \
    ac_taxation_std_test \
    bc_product_pricing_test \
    bc_order_test \
    bc_payment_test \
    bc_orderprocess_test \
    sld_pmc_test \
    app_bo_cms_test \
    app_bo_dashboard_test \
    bc_search_test \
    bc_store_test \
    bc_image_test \
    bc_dashboard_test \
    app_bo_test \
    app_sf_contactcenter_rest_test \
    app_sf_rest_test \
    ac_search_solr_test \
    bc_urlrewrite_test \
    bc_product_rating_orm_test \
    ac_order_submission_service_test \
    test_app_sf \
    test_app_cm \
    pmc_unit_testing \
    commerce_management_b2c_component \
    core_a1 \
    app_core_a1 \
    bc_a1_orm \
    service_a1_esb \
    service_a1_siebel \
    service_a1_sap \
    ac_payment_cccorvus \
    app_sf_responsive \
    app_sf_responsive_cm \
    app_sf_responsive_b2c \
    app_sf_responsive_smb \
    as_responsive \
    app_sf_responsive_gdpr \
    app_sf_a1_tomato \
    app_sf_a1_tomato_cm \
    app_sf_a1_shop \
    app_sf_a1_shop_cm \
    as_a1 \
    app_bo_a1 \
    dev_storefront \
    app_sf_responsive_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that we were trying to override the template from the intershop.SLDSystem application in our custom storefront cartridge that wasn't assigned to that application.

Since we don't override any other functionalities of that application, we have decided to go with a different approach instead of overriding the template.

Alternative solution is:

1. Define a BO short link that redirects /urlerror to Error-Start?ErrorCode=PageNotFound
2. Override Error-Start pipeline and add handling for the "PageNotFound" error code ending with a custom template

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to override the pipelines. To be honest I have no idea why your wizard isn't showing the `.isml` templates. On my ISH `7.9` The override wizard shows all `.isml` files from the `sld_system_app` cartridge as soon as I add `compile group: 'com.intershop.business', name: 'sld_system_app'` to the `build.gradle` file of my custom cartridge and refresh the gradle dependencies.

A possible solution would be to override the `URLError.isml` file manually and see if that works. To do this recreate the folder structure `staticfiles/cartridge/templates/default/application` in your custom cartridge and create the `URLError.isml` in there manually.

Comment: Unfortunately, overriding the ISML manually doesn't work either, we have tried that already. We have compile group: 'com.intershop.business', name: 'sld_system_app' in the build.gradle and dependencies are obviously refreshed (since we can override any pipeline from that cartridge) but overriding the template just doesn't work...

Comment: I have updated my initial question. We have managed to get the override wizard working but we still cannot override the page. The system template is still getting rendered before our custom ISML.

Comment: Make sure that your cartridge is assigned to the correct application (intershop.SLDSystem) by using a component file.